# Server side events

Tags: spring

I have to implement a notification callback url, which would receive some data from an external application. Once it receives the data, it should post that data in my application.I am using spring rest API for creating notification callback url. The problem that I have now is how to send that data to the browser. Any idea on how can I implement this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is too broad for SO. You need to do some research by your own before (Google, Spring docs, ...), try something, and then post what you have tried, if it's not working.

Comment: The question is do you want a single client to read the output from your server process or all clients to see it. i.e. is it a point-to-point message or broadcast ? For p2p, I'd use websockets and for broadcasts SSE would work better.